# Is there a way to render a page differently based on if a user is logged in or not (using Jinja2/Flask/Python)

Tags: python, html, flask, web, jinja2

I'm creating my first basic web app using Jinja2, Flask, and Python.

I have some html for a nav-bar that I'd like to render dynamically depending on if a user is logged in or not. Is something you can do easily with the stack I'm working in?

A small example would be really helpful! Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest you to look at [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable that states whether the user is logged in or not you could do something like:

```
<a href="/home">Home</a>
{% if logged_in %}
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
<a href="/login">Login</a>
<a href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %}
```

Also, I would recommend using a module called flask-login to make creating a login system easier

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).